# Multiple arity static type constraint

Tags: f#, type-constraints

Let's say I have a bunch of vector types (a la XNA) and some of them have static member `Cross`:

```
type Vector3 =
  ...
  static member Cross (a : Vector3, b : Vector3) = new Vector3(...)
```

I can define the `cross` function and it compiles:

```
let inline cross (x : ^T) (y : ^T) = (^T : (static member Cross : (^T * ^T) -> ^T) ((x,y)))
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to use it and have following error:

```
let res = cross a b
                 ^
```

> The member or object constructor Cross
>   takes 2 argument(s) but is here given
>   1. The required signature is static member Vector3.Cross :
>   a:Vector3 * b:Vector3 ->
>   Vector3

Is it even possible at all? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've over-parenthesized your static member signature.  Try this instead:

```
let inline cross (x : ^T) (y : ^T) = 
  (^T : (static member Cross : ^T * ^T -> ^T) (x,y))
```

Given your definition, F# was looking for a member `Cross` which takes a single argument of tuple type.